# ignore lines grep

Tags: grep, regex, ignore

I have a very annoying message being output from a process I'm running. I'd rather not remove the line, but simply remove it with grep

The messages to ignore all contain the word "requests". I could easily ONLY these lines with

```
$> myproc | grep requests
```

How would I make grep instead IGNORE lines with the word requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the -v option:

`myproc | grep -v requests`

Comment: Oh wow. That is too easy. Thanks so much! :-) I'll accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry can't resist:

```
myproc | perl -ne "/requests/ or print"
```

that's a perl one liner that uses `-e` to execute code on the command line, and `-n` to wrap it in a while loop reading one line at a time.  The `/requests/` part is a match against any line that contains the word 'requests`.  Putting it all together says, "if the line doesn't contain the word 'requests', print it out."

This is a  contrived example since Robin Green points out that `grep -v` works just fine in your case.  However you can extend this perl one liner to make an arbitrarily complex filter.